# How to create sockets that particular to user and disposable on Socket.Io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I write a Node.Js app and I use Socket.Io as the data transfer system, so requests should be particular to per user. How can I make this?

My actual code;

node:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('loginP', data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
})
```

js:

```
var socket = io('',{forceNew : false});

$("#loginbutton").click(function() {
    var sessionInfo = {
        name : $("#login input[name='username']").val(),
        pass : $("#login input[name='pass']").val()
    }

    socket.emit("loginP", sessionInfo)

})
```

It returns one more data for per request and this is a problem for me. Can I make this on Socket.Io or should I use another module, and If I should, which module?

Comment: Can you explain where `it returns one more data for per request`.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande For instance, on the first using ıt returns only one data as it should be, but on the second using it returns both of first and second data. Actually I'm not sure about I use correct module for this but I couldn't find a better way for data transferring on Node.Js.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly (It's possible I don't), you want to have just one connection from each user's browser to your nodejs program.

On the nodejs side, your `io.on('connection'...)` event fires with each new incoming user connection, and gives you the `socket` for that specific connection. So, keep track of your sockets; you'll have one socket per user.

On the browser side, you should build your code to ensure it only calls

```
var socket = io(path, ...);
```

once for each path (your path is `''`).  The`forceNew` option is for situations where you have multiple paths from one program.

Comment: I think I should clarify myself better.  I was using ajax and PHP for transferring data previously, so I was transmitting the user requests and responses with AJAX to server-side or client-side. But I've begun to learn NodeJs and I couldn't find a useful way to transfer users' requests and response except for Socket.Io. So, I'm trying to make a login system to create a session. Hence,  only one request should be transmitted to server-side, they shouldn't be stored, so If a user enters wrong information, he or she should be able to try second time. And sockets should be particular to each user.